# Python - PRINT_ERRORS=0 or 1

Tags: python, exception, printing, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am new to python , I am executing a small code, I see below code written at the start of my code

PRINT_ERRORS=0

if I run the code as it is, it works fine, however if I change the value to 1 if prints some errors, I want to understand what that line of code is doing there, can anyone help?

I am not sure what should I expect from this line of code

Answer (score 0):

```
PRINT_ERRORS=0
```

As per your question, it is variable which is holding the value 0 in it.
More Information will be required to give you specific about the activity of line